# Wrapping an AImage* from the Android NDK containing a NV21 frame in a cv::Mat

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I’m writing an NDK based application and am getting YUV image data fed into a surface which is delivered to my code in an [AImage](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/media#aimage_delete)* structure. If the image is coming from the camera, it can be semi-planar in NV21 form so one plane of Y and then one plane of VU of same width but half the height. If the image is coming from the decoder then I get planar YUV420 so 3 planes with the U and V planes with 1/4 the number of pixels.

I want to wrap this in a cv::Mat using one of [the constructors](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a) that accept an external data pointer. I know how to detect if I’m getting semi planar or planar YUVs. The problem is that I’m not sure that the all the planes that comes from the NDK is a contiguous block. Furthermore, the dimensions for the planes are not the same since there are fewer pixels in the UV plains. How would I go about wrapping the AImage. Has anyone done something like this before? Do I have to memcopy the data in a single plane in cv::Mat?

Comment: Have you tried using `AImage_getFormat`/`getNumberOfPlanes`/`getPlanePixelStride`/`getPlaneRowStride` to get more information about the image?

Comment: Yes I did use those functions to get information. The issue isnt' that I can't get the information. The issue is that the multiplanar AImage has different buffers for the plane and it looks like OpenCV expects it to be in a single allocation. Some of the code I've seen online expects it to be single channel (since the planes don't have the same dimensions). I just want to see if there is a way to wrap in a cv::Mat without copying the data out.

Comment: You are looking for [cvtColorTwoPlane](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga8e873314e72a1a6c0252375538fbf753) for the NV21 case. You can't express any of the chroma subsampled formats as single OpenCV mat in the first place (other than for the purpose of using the NV21 / 12 conversions which understand that for the single buffer signature the bottom 1/3rd of rows is UV), and neither can OpenCV cope with multi planar buffers either. [mixChannels](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga51d768c270a1cdd3497255017c4504be) for merging.